# R: Convert "Multiple Hyphonated Years" Factor values into datetime value

Tags: r, datetime-format

I have a column `Season` in my dataframe `NBAS`which has values of NBA seasons in the format `"1989-90"`

I would love to change this value to a datetime value so this subset will work:

```
summary(lm(X3PA ~ W.L., data = subset(NBAS, NBAS$Season > '1989-90')))
```

Edit 3: Above was edited to show more context

Right now it is giving me the error message:

```
Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) : 
  0 (non-NA) cases
In addition: Warning message:
In Ops.factor(NBAS$Season, "1989-90") : ‘>’ not meaningful for factors
```

Thanks!

Edit1:
Per NicE's suggestion I simply removed the hyphen and changed the format to numeric using:

```
NBAS$Season <- gsub("-", "", NBA$Season)
NBAS$Season <- as.numeric(NBAS$Season)
```

Then I was able to use the subset correctly.

Comment: Any format is fine with me, even if it is not a day format.  I just need to be able to have the column orderable so I can subset the data for seasons after the "1989-90" season.

Comment: Why can't you remove the hyphen and treat them as a number?

Comment: Thanks NicE, that worked well.

Comment: @NicE why not post that as an answer, so its clear there is an answer or alternatively cptnhaddock could put the answer in the answer section.

Comment: I don't think that the full context was offered. That error message should not have been triggered by that code. There is no reason that `lm.fit` would be called by `subset`.

Comment: Good call, did not think of that. Will change tomorrow when I have access to the computer I did this on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try removing the hyphen and treating them as number:

```
NBAS$Season <- as.numeric(gsub("-","",Season))
```

Comment: Actually, it would be less destructive to use `as.character`. Character values accept the `>` Comparison operator without complaint.